# Vue Js Store Management

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

Not able to access store.getters.method in my js file while i am getting sotre.getters method in console.

In x.js

```
import {store} from '../../store/store'
```

Getting method changeValue in

```
console.log(store.getters);
```

but when i am accessing it using below it is giving "[**ob**: Observer, property1: 42]"

```
console.log(store.getters.changeValue);
```

Comment: can you please include/attach your JS file.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to access store in js file not in vue component. I am accessing it in x.js file. so if i accessing it through store.getters.UnitCounters but it is giving "undefined". while it has value when i access it through sotre.getters.

Answer (score 0):

You might get the [ob: Observer] while trying to access getters through store directly. And it is not a recommended way of doing so.

Try using mapGetters in your computed properties of the JS file which you are using. Something like:

```
computed:{
        ...mapGetters(['changeValue'])
},
```

After which you can access changeValue in this(vm instance). So just call

```
this.changeValue
```

You can read more about mapGetters [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Anikt! But i need to access in JS file not in component. so i don't have computed property here.